# Is it possible to duplicate a row based on a column value, and change another column value?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with an INT column of time in seconds, another column with the type of that record, and a foreign ID.

I want to select the same row repeated everytime it's seconds row is greater than X, and in the first row it keeps X seconds with type 1, and in the second row it shows the seconds left (seconds - X, up to X) with type 2. The same with Y. No more than 3 rows. So row 1 is up to x, row 2 up to Y and row 3 is Y+1 and beyond

Eg:

X is 5. Y is 9.
I want this:

```
| id | type | seconds |
|----|------|---------|
|  1 |  10  |   19    |
|  2 |  10  |   12    |
|  3 |  10  |    7    |
```

to become this:

```
| id | type | seconds |
|----|------|---------|
|  1 |   1  |    5    |
|  1 |   2  |    4    |
|  1 |   3  |   10    |
|  2 |   1  |    5    |
|  2 |   2  |    4    |
|  2 |   3  |    3    |
|  3 |   1  |    5    |
|  3 |   2  |    2    |
```

Is that possible?

I've seen solutions to this (syntax-) exclusively for oracle.
But how do I do this in SQL Server?

Edit: Only for this type id (10 in the example), letting others unchanged.

Comment: I don't fully understand how do you divide your seconds and why does the value changes to 14 for id 1.

Comment: @LuisCazares sorry, my bad. It's 19 seconds, I've edited it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not very pretty, but does the trick. To duplicate rows, we use tally tables. In this case I used a hard coded one with only 3 rows. Then made the calculations based on it. There might be a simpler way to code it, but I'm not on my best today.

```
--Creating sample data
CREATE TABLE SampleData(
    id      int,
    [type]  int,
    seconds int
);

INSERT INTO SampleData
VALUES
( 1, 10, 19),
( 2, 10, 12),
( 3, 10,  7),
( 4, 10, 5),
( 5, 10,  3);
GO

--Actual solution
DECLARE @X int = 5;

WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT id,
        CASE WHEN [type] =  10 THEN n ELSE [type] END AS [type],
        CASE WHEN [type] <> 10 THEN seconds
             WHEN n = 1 AND seconds > @X THEN @X
             WHEN n = 1 AND seconds <= @X THEN seconds
             WHEN n = 2 AND seconds - @X >= @X THEN @X-1
             WHEN n = 2 AND seconds - @X > 0 THEN seconds - @X
             WHEN n = 3 AND seconds > @X*2-1 THEN seconds - (@X*2-1)
             END AS seconds
    FROM SampleData
    CROSS JOIN( VALUES(1),(2),(3))AS x(n)
    WHERE [type] = 10 OR n = 1
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE seconds IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Cool. I doing a quick research on this, and as I not from the USA, I didn't even knew this term 'tally tables', even though it is a simple thing. Since I'm not so familiar with this, I will wait for another answer; in the meantime I will study it and try to adapt it to my context. Thanks!

Comment: Luis, does this work even with different types? I mean, type 10 is what I want to duplicate but type 15 remain intact.

Comment: I made some changes on the code to duplicate rows only for type 10.

Comment: Luis, I ended up using your code, for the simplicity. The final code had some changes (such as another variable for the second interval) but yours fit well into my problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

For this type of problem I like to use a [recursive CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Borrowed the extra test cases from @Luis Cazares. Also added test cases for type 15 you mentioned in comments. In the solution below you can swap out values of X and Y and it will calculate accordingly.

```
CREATE TABLE #TestData
(
    id INT
    , type INT
    , seconds int
);

INSERT INTO #TestData VALUES
(1, 10, 19)
, (2, 10, 12)
, (3, 10, 7)
, (4, 10, 5)
, (5, 10, 3)
, (6, 15, 54)
, (7, 15, 8);

DECLARE 
    @X INT = 5
    , @Y INT = 9;

SET @Y = @Y - @X;

WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT id, CASE WHEN type = 10 THEN 0 ELSE type END AS type, seconds, seconds AS ov 
    FROM #TestData
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        id
        , type + 1
        , CASE
            WHEN type = 0 THEN seconds - @X
            WHEN type = 1 THEN seconds - @Y
            WHEN type = 2 THEN seconds
            END
        , ov
    FROM CTE
    WHERE seconds > 0
)

SELECT
    id
    , type
    , CASE
        WHEN type = 1 AND seconds > 0 THEN @X
        WHEN type = 2 AND seconds > 0 THEN @Y
        WHEN type = 2 AND seconds < 0 THEN ov - @X
        WHEN type = 3 AND seconds > 0 THEN seconds
        ELSE ov
        END
FROM CTE
WHERE type <> 0 AND CTE.seconds IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY id, type

DROP TABLE #TestData;
```

Comment: I usually avoid recursive CTEs if a different option is available. Not only recursion is something that some people have trouble understanding, but it also seems to be slower in many cases. For example, if we create 100,000 rows, it becomes evident that it's 5 times slower and has 10 times more reads.